# How to generate PDF from .cfm page in Mac

Tags: coldfusion

I am using `<cfdocument>` tag of coldfusion 7. Using CFEclipse and working on MacOS.
I have written the following code:

```
<cfdocument format="pdf">
 SitePoint.com - Introduction to ColdFusion 7
 PDF Generation
 This is an example of PDF generation using ColdFusion 7.
</cfdocument>
```

**But instead of asking me to save this file in .pdf format, its trying to open it in .cfm format.** 
How can I save it in .pdf format? Thanks!

Comment: that code is valid. it should work.  is there anything else on the page?

Comment: No, that was the only content on .cfm page. I got the answer tough.
Thanks!!

Comment: We have to use
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=myDoc.pdf"> on the top of the page. It will force .cfm page to be downloaded as .pdf page. 
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/554271

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you tell it otherwise, the webserver returns the results of a CFM call as text.  You need to use CFContent with CFHeader to alert the browser that the results it will be recieving are of a different type.  Something like:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=document.pdf"> 
<cfcontent type="application/x-pdf"> 
<cfdocument>...</cfdocument>
```

I may have the MIME type wrong there.  I'm doing this from memory.  Check the docs for more help.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on CF8 or higher then use the saveAsName attribute:

```
<cfdocument saveAsName=""
```

Either that or the method suggested by Ben above should work

Comment: Nice tip.  I didn't know about that.  I should really pay more attention to changelogs.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to import the style sheet as well. So you can get the desired formatting. It needs to be imported after cfdocument.

```
 <cfdocument 
 format="pdf" 
 filename = "canwriteurfile.pdf"
 overwrite = "yes"
 marginBottom = ".2"
 marginLeft = ".4"
 marginRight = ".4"
 marginTop = ".2">

 <style type="text/css">@import "pdf.css";</style>

  BLAHHH BLAHHH PDF FORMATTING STUFF

 </cfdocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" name="myPDF">
 <html>
  <body>
   SitePoint.com - Introduction to ColdFusion 7
   PDF Generation
   This is an example of PDF generation using ColdFusion 7.
  </body>
 </html>
</cfdocument>

<cfpdf action = "write" destination = "pdf_path" source = "myPDF" overwrite = "yes"/>

<cflocation url="pdf_path"/>
```

Whis this you save the PDF on disk